# Is there a way to get the total Flops in an inference pass for a given pytorch or tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I have been studying the [Nvidia WaveGlow model](https://github.com/NVIDIA/waveglow) that's used by Nvidia in text-to-speech synthesis, but couldn't find any estimate of # of Flops in the inference for this model.

One can easily print out the model in pytorch using `print(waveglow)` and count the parameters. Similarly for Tensorflow one can do `tf.trainable_variables()` to count model-parameters.
But I couldn't see a way to at least get ball-park estimate of # of operations.

Is there a way to compute approximately total operations/Flops for a model for a given datatype, say fp32? For both Pytorch and Tensorflow?